# Long Stem Roses or Long Stemmed Roses?

Tags: phrases

On [gardeningknowhow.com](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/flowers/roses/long-stem-roses.htm) I read:

> ## What is a Long Stem Rose?
>
> When we refer to long stemmed roses, we are typically speaking of
> Hybrid Tea roses...etc.

I'm not sure if this is a language question or a horticulture question, or maybe both. Are both terms, "Long Stem Rose" and "Long Stemmed Rose" correct, and if so, are they synonymous?

Comment: As far as I know, they mean the same thing. (They are both grammatical.) I find it very strange that the article referenced is not consistent in the naming that it uses.

Comment: Correct or not I don't see how they could not be synonymous. I would have hyphenated "long-stemmed" and not used "long stem" like that at all.

Comment: Soft-shelled crabs or soft-shell crabs? Compounds made from old participles often lose the participial suffix, especially in the middle of what might as well be considered a word. Like the plurals of _attorney general_ or _mother-in-law_, this causes problems, which are normally solved by ignoring the detail.

Answer (score 2):

We're looking partly for precising or stipulative definitions of the terms.

[FloraQueen](https://www.floraqueen.com/blog/long-stem-roses) indeed uses the (attributive) term with a stipulative definition (thus as a compound noun):

> *Long stem roses, regardless of the variations we have today, are a
> hybrid species, and they came about as a result of cross-breeding
> between tea roses and hybrid perpetual roses. This revolutionary
> cross-breeding was done sometime in the 1800s and has given birth to
> the variety of long stem roses that we have in the modern world.*

But [Teleflora](https://www.teleflora.com/blog/what-makes-a-rose-long-stemmed/), one would expect having a certain authority, implies that the attributive usage is merely a collocation:

*Roses are sold by length, in centimeters – there isn’t a floral industry-wide standard for the length of the ‘medium stem’ or ‘long stem’ roses. But below is an approximate guide....*

The *Gardening Know How* excerpt also implies a degree of mixed usage (' ... we are typically speaking of ...'). So it seems that one has to be careful how to interpret the string 'long stem rose': a hybrid species resulting from cross-breeding between tea roses and hybrid perpetual roses, or any rose with an arbitrarily long stem.

..........................

As for the attributive vs participial adjective usage, the *Gardening Know How* article uses them both without making a distinction.

And [these Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=long+stem+rose%2Clong+stemmed+rose&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clong%20stem%20rose%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clong%20stemmed%20rose%3B%2Cc0) show no vast difference in their currency:

[image]

Both alternatives are totally grammatical; hyphenation is unnecessary as 'stem roses' and 'stemmed roses' are not compounds or strong collocates.

Answer (score 1):

I agree. I would say long-stemmed roses.

I researched to see whether this was correct, since florists advertise them in many different ways (long stem roses, long stemmed roses, long-stem roses, long-stemmed roses).

I found this link: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/long-stemmed
So, I would go with long-stemmed roses.

Comment: Your answer only quotes a link as the basis of your opinion. Answers on SE need to be self-contained. Quote the entry in this dictionary and, if possible, explain the grammatical or other reasoning behind the conclusion.  What do you think is wrong with “long stemmed roses”?